# Is creating a new table each time a user logs in a bad practice?

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I am developing an online inventory management system. I have one table for the main inventory which consists of the product names, quantity and barcodes etc. I want users to log into the system each morning and log the quantity of each item they take. I then want to store this information for the admin to view. I have developed the system so that a new table gets created each morning based on the users name and date. This is allows the user to input the quantity for each product, i then subtract that column from the main inventory table when the user clicks submit. I want to know if this is a bad practice, is it necessary to create a new table each morning? If not what method should i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should maintain a single table for inventory, and then after a create a temporary table to store the list of items the user takes which will contain the user id, inventory id, qty etc, and then update the quantity of inventory in inventory table, whenever user picks the inventory.

In short you should create a single table to store the information of inventory which user takes instead of creating a new table each day.

Insert and fetch data according to date + user.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you are creating new table everyday, you should not create new table in any case. In the rarest scenario even if your columns are dynamic then create a table with rows representing as column and use pivot to fetch the record. For your use case you just need to have a table which stores a new record and subtract the count from main table.